# Google ReCAPTCHA Too many Request

Tags: google-chrome, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I have added ReCAPTCHA to the login area on my website, however when I try to login it always comes up Too Many Request in every browser. If I delete the cookies it goes again until I log in. How can I solve this problem?

I have inserted the 2 keys from the google Site.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter the error message:

```
Google reCaptcha:Too Many Requests
```

this means that you have exceeded  the usage limits for reCaptcha service. It prevents abuse and ensures fair usage of the reCaptcha service. It indicates that you sent too many requests within a short period of time.

This is usually temporary and a few minutes to one hour of waiting  then retry should be sufficient. If it still doesn't work, I suggest implementing [rate limiting](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/bot-management#rate-limiting) to your reCaptcha resources.

> For security, we recommend that you configure rate limiting rules to prevent token abuse through multiple uses per unique reCAPTCHA action-token, session-token, or exemption cookie.